Cropping an image with rounded borders in MAUI
I am trying to get a very simple rounded corner Image in .NET MAUI, in a layout like so:
<Grid Margin="16, 20" RowDefinitions="*, auto">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" 
               Aspect="AspectFit" 
               Grid.Row="0">
            <Image.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:ClipToBoundsBehavior />
            </Image.Behaviors>
        </Image>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="End">
        <!-- some buttons you don't need to worry about -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>

It is essentially just a grid with a big area for the image in the middle, and the size and source of the image can be freely changed.
What I have tried:

Creating a Frame or a Border surrounding the image, and round the corners that way:

Since the whole thing is wrapped in a Grid with row height *, the Frame or Border ends up stretching the whole screen.
I then tried to fetch the Image's requested Height upon Content Page Loaded, and dynamically change the height of the Frame that way, and even in this function here



    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
        ImageHeight = Image.Height;
    }

The height returns a huge number (~2000) and does not work. I'm not sure why.

Creating a Clip for the image, using a custom ClipToBoundsBehavior that will change the shape as the image's shape changes. The Image will render, but does not clip at all, or clip at very random numbers that is not the Image's height and width. Here is my ClipToBoundsBehavior class:

public class ClipToBoundsBehavior : Behavior<Image>
{
    private RoundRectangleGeometry _clipGeometry;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Image bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        _clipGeometry = new RoundRectangleGeometry { CornerRadius = 15 };   

        bindable.Clip = _clipGeometry;

        bindable.SizeChanged += Bindable_SizeChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Image bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        bindable.SizeChanged -= Bindable_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void Bindable_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Image image)
        {
            _clipGeometry.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
            image.Clip = _clipGeometry;
        }
    }
}

I am still quite new at this, so any help on deepening my understanding of how this works is completely welcomed. I am also not against trying different routes, since I am getting quite frustrated on how difficult it has been for such a simple thing. Unless I am missing something here.
I appreciate you guys' help!

If you just want a nice rounded picture to show in your app, you can use Image.Clip. There are also great examples in the samples repo, so go there a take a look if this is not what you wanted.
<Image
    Grid.Column="0"
    Aspect="AspectFill"
    HeightRequest="50"
    Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
    WidthRequest="50">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry
            Center="25,25"
            RadiusX="25"
            RadiusY="25" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>




This is not what I wanted, since I want the picture to be dynamically sized and here you have to specify a height. I also have tried Image.Clip, where I implemented it using ClipToBoundsBehavior.

Ok, but with this you can make it dynamic, if the image I show is the outcome you want.

How do I make this dynamic? You have to specify a HeightRequest and WidthRequest to achieve the shape. In my case, the image is wrapped within a Grid with RowHeight *, so the image will stretch, and I want to be able to change out the images, where they will have different heights and widths.
That was also why I tried pulling in the image's width and height when it is changed, and update the clip shape in ClipToBoundsBehavior, but I have yet to get it to work.

About Clip you can see this case: MAUI how to use clip.
